# Как сделать смену языка сайта без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, локализация, перевод

На сайте есть кнопка смены языка, при ее нажатии все фразы на сайте надо перевести на другой язык(фразы с верным переводом уже заготовлены).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно реализовать смену языка без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: Это можно реализовать с помощью HTML, CSS, JS. При этом можно не обновлять страницу. А если серьезно - то вопрос слишком общий и скорей всего его закроют, т.к. слишком мало деталей и (еще раз) он слишком общий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать как-то так:

```js
let rus = {
  hello: 'Привет',
  lorem: 'Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. <br><br><br>В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов.',
  ipsum: ' Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. <br>Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.',
};

let eng = {
  hello: 'hello',
  lorem: 'At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.',
  ipsum: 'Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. <br>Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.',
};

changeLagnuage();

function changeLagnuage(){
  let language = lang.checked ? rus : eng;
  document.querySelectorAll('[text]').forEach(el => {
    el.innerHTML = language[el.getAttribute('text')];
  })
}
```

```css
#lang {
  display: none;
}
#lang:checked ~ .rus,   
#lang:not(:checked) ~ .eng {
  display:none;
}
label[for="lang"] {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="lang" type='checkbox' onclick="changeLagnuage()">
<label for="lang" class="rus">RUS</label><label for="lang" class="eng">ENG</label>
<h1 text="hello"></h1>
<h2 text="lorem"></h2>
<h3 text="ipsum"></h3>
```

Comment: А как использовать <br> в тексте?

Comment: можно устанавливать innerHTML, сейчас изменю ответ